# Add an question mark to the redirected link in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Sample URL: `tedsite.com/watch_video.php?v=c4603cc14419a0639fb5`

This should be redirected to: `tedsite.com/watch?v=c4603cc14419a0639fb5`

I've tried to redirect using, but it is not working:

```
RewriteRule ^watch?v=(.*) watch_video.php?v=$1 [nc]
```

And:

```
RewriteRule ^watch\?v=(.*) watch_video.php?v=$1 [nc]
```

This works without the question mark, but I need it in the link:

```
RewriteRule ^watchv=(.*) watch_video.php?v=$1 [nc]
```

How can I add the question mark to the redirected link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot match query string in `RewriteRule`. Use `RewriteCond` instead like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^v=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^watch/?$ watch_video.php?v=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: +1, I always like seeing your `%{QUERY_STRING}` conditions. By the way you added `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews`, is there a reason for this particular pattern or is it just something that you feel is helpful to avoid problems in general?

Comment: Yes there was a reason why I added it here. It is because `/watch` is being forwarded to `/watch.php` and if `MultiViews` is on then query string will be missing since Apache's content negotiation module rune before `mod_rewrite` to make the URI `/watch.php` and rule won't even run.